# joomla readmore showing next page instead of the first

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I m using JCE and whenever i m giving "readmore" button for the article, that article is displaying the data in first page which is actually should come after clicking readmore link

please help in this issue

thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH!!

I noticed that readmore is not for "Article Layout", so I have to use the "Pagebreak"

And inside plugin manager, disable 
"Site Title"
"Table of Contents"
"Show all"

and inside plugins/content/pagebreak.php

comment these lines

```
//  $row->text .= '<div class="pagenavcounter">';
//  $row->text .= $pageNav->getPagesCounter();
//  $row->text .= '</div>';
```

that's it.

and "Pagebreak" will work as expected. Now I don't need "readmore" anywhere!!

Thanks